# Is it possible to create a mailing system in .NET?

Tags: .net, email, newsletter

I have to create a project for my .NET classes. I came up with an idea of create email newsletter or autoresponder. I have to make it in 3 stages: 1. desktop application (in Windows Forms or WPF), 2. browser application, 3. mobile application.

Is this thing doable in .NET? I just need to know whether sending emails is possible in .NET applications and whether it's relatively easy or too complicated to care about this idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.NET` comes with an inbuilt function that makes sending emails super easy. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Keep in mind that you will still need to provide .NET with an SMTP server.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-server.MyDomain.com"))
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;

        mail.From = new MailAddress("MyEmail@MyDomain.com");
        mail.To.Add("ToThisEmail@MyDomain.com");

        client.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 from me for adding example code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the .NET framework supports sending out emails.

See the [System.Net.Mail namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx), or look for a 3rd party library if you need something more advanced.